# Why can't my C++ algorithm handle integers more than 62 bits?

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer, long-integer

I was playing around with C++ and decided to write algorithm that would return bit length of given integer. After solving a few not-related issues it finally worked. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long int ipow(int x,int n)
{
    if (n==0)   return 1;
    if (n%2!=0) return x*ipow(x,((n-1)/2))*ipow(x,((n-1)/2));
    return      ipow(x,n/2)*ipow(x,n/2);
}

int bits(long long int n)
{
    if (n==0 || n==1) return 1;
    int i=1;
    while (n>ipow(2,i+1)-1) i++;
    return i+1;
}

int main()
{
    long long int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<bits(n)<<endl;
}
```

I've tested it with bigger and bigger numbers and discovered interesting fact - program was really fast for most integers, even larger (50-60 bit long), but was stuck at high CPU load and not displaying anything for minutes with numbers "a little" bigger.

I modified code a little bit to find the breaking point and discovered that the last integer my program can process is 4611686018427387903. I looked it up on Wolfram Alpha and found out that it equals 2^63-1, meaning it's the largest 62-bit number.

There lyes my question - it can be stupid - why 62-bit? As I understand, *long long int* can hold 64-bit variables, my CPU can also process 64-bit integers. So why isn't 64-bit the limit?

-Mateusz Duchalski

PS I'm using Code::Blocks with latest stable MinGW running on Windows 10 64-bit powered by Intel Core i5-4570 Haswell CPU.

Comment: `long long` is signed, so that at least explains one of the "missing" bits - the sign bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because 1 bit is the sign bit, so that leaves 63 "useful" bits.. and your algorithm tries to find a power-of-2 that is larger than your input number, so your largest input number can only be 62 bits so that your power-of-2 can go 1 higher to 63 bits.

Comment: Could he make it unsigned to give that extra bit of precision?

Comment: I didn't look closely at the code to see if anything else would break, but yeah, he generally should be able to get an extra bit by going unsigned.

Comment: Using unsigned integer worked. I now get correct results up to 2^65-1. After that every number returns '64', but simple 'if' can deal with it.